# How to replace first word of line in Python?

Tags: python, csv, parsing

My input file data is like this.

```
0,@rodriigoCabrera y tu vaso tu silla y tu baño

1,Mexican rival demands vote recount: The leader of Mexico's leftist Party of the Democratic Revolution, Andres Ma...

0,Queretaro 0 - 3 Morelia Tarjeta amarilla a Carlos Adrián Morales Higuera
```

I want to replace all the 0 in the first column with false and 1 with true.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck - seems like a simple `split()` `join()` problem. Or if you are using `csv` then `row[0] = <mapped-value>`

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new to this one so it would be great if you can suggest me code example

Comment: Much, much easier to write a new file and then rename it to the original name.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with something like this:

```
with open('file1', 'rU') as f:
    for line in f:
        # split the line (only once) on a comma
        value, rest = line.split(',', 1)

        # join the line back together, but change the 1/0 to true/false
        print(','.join(('true' if int(value) else 'false', rest)))
```

#### Results:

```
false,@rodriigoCabrera y tu vaso tu silla y tu baÃ±o    
true,Mexican rival demands vote recount: The leader of Mexico's leftist Party of the Democratic Revolution, Andres Ma...    
false,Queretaro 0 - 3 Morelia Tarjeta amarilla a Carlos AdriÃ¡n Morales Higuera
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newfile = []
with open('input.txt', 'rU') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if line[0] == "0":
            line = line.replace("0", "False", 1)
        elif line[0] == "1":
            line = line.replace("1", "True", 1)
        newfile.append(line)

with open('output.txt', 'w') as output:
    print('\n'.join(newfile), file=output)
```